# Save response of web service to JSON text files in batch

Tags: sql, json, rest, azure, web

i have a web service JSON in Azure and there i request the following:

```
http://mywebsite.com/details/(GAMECODE)/(LANGUAGE)
```

this information is static and since i have a lot of games i want to off-load the server what means i want to store the response of each request as an text file, like such:

```
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345673/ENGLISH.json
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345673/DUTCH.json
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345673/GERMAN.json
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345674/ENGLISH.json
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345674/DUTCH.json
http://mywebsite.com/detailsStatic/345674/GERMAN.json
```

etc etc

Each file of course holds the JSON response data, how would i be able to do this automatically for each `gamecode` and save the responses in different text files in a single folder? Is there a program that would be able to do this in a batch (run a long list of excel copied inside as example?) or should can i do it with code? Postman just allows me one by one so that no good idea :)

Who has some good leads that i could follow?
Websites to read about or idea`s to get me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like curl, wget or [aria2](https://aria2.github.io) to download a list of files.
see this [command](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=aria2c+-j5+-i+list.txt): `aria2c -j5 -i list.txt`

Comment: very useful aria2c, command line, simple dos batch with a loop did the trick, could not be faster and better, thanks, works perfect